# How to make msnbot not end up in my bot trap?

Tags: php, html, bing, nofollow

Is there an alternative way to tell Bing not to crawl/pass/click/enter a certain link such as google's rel=nofollow?

msnbot/2.0b keeps getting trapped in my bot trap. It does not obey anchor tag rel="nofollow".

Limits:

- I can't add the link to robots.txt because the link is a dynamic parameter key i.e. 
  anypage.php?xirh398. The key is unique for each session and changes every 5 minutes.
- I can't use a meta tag beacause the trap is not a page.
- I can't use a HTTP header because the bot will already have been banned by then.
- I don't want to continously update whitelists.

Comment: Well, whatever words I must put instead. Google doesn't enter the link and I don't bing to do it either.

Comment: Checkout the four methods to [remove URLs from Bing index](http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2009/06/08/how-to-remove-urls-from-our-index-expanded-edition.aspx). You can also use [Bing webmaster tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster) to specify how Bing should treat your website.

Answer (score 2):

> It does not obey anchor tag rel="nofollow".

`nofollow` means "Don't give weight to this link in search results". It doesn't mean "This is not a real link, don't follow it". (Yes, that is unintuitive).

If you want Good Bots to stay out of a part of your website, [use a `robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) to tell them about it.